# IBM Domino IMAP Task not returning Sent folder via IMAP

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap, lotus-domino

I am using **JavaMail** (1.5.2) to load mail messages via **IMAP**. After connecting to the IMAPStore (store), I use the command `store.getDefaultFolder().list("*")` to get a list of all the folders.

For standard mail accounts, like GMail or Yahoo, this works perfectly fine and I get all available folders. However, when using **IBM Domino** (8.5.3 / 9.0.1) via IMAP, I only get the inbox plus my personal folders that I created manually, but the **Sent folder is missing**. Does anybody know how I could fix this?

Comment: I may be wrong but your question might be better off @ http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/lotus-domino

Comment: @LotharMueller: Thanks for the advice. I will post it at serverfault in case I can't find a solution here.

Comment: The IBM Traveler task doesn't support/run IMAP. That's the underlying Domino server.

Comment: @muenzpraeger: Thanks for the info. I thought that the Traveler would have to be installed on the server in order for this to work. Are you sure that the server would still support IMAP access even without the Traveler?

Comment: Sent is a view, not a folder. Since that is the only one you say that is missing, I suspect this may be functioning as designed - i.e., . I'a known limitation and not actually a bug. But I'm not sure about that. It's just a guess.

Comment: IMAP is a Domino service which has been there way before Traveler.

http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/Rnext/help6_admin.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/3a89e0cc5329e70485256c1d003963b4?OpenDocument

Answer (score 1):

The `EnableImapFolderSynch` INI parameter may do what you want: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21670355

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I checked the notes.ini and the parameter EnableImapFolderSynch is already set to 1.

Comment: Did you enable the mailfile in question for imap using the command `load convert -e mail\mailfile.nsf`as stated in the [admin- help](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/conf_runningthemailconversionutilitytoenableamailfile_t.dita?)